# REQL - Using Filter with (regex) Match, and then Pluck from a list in a nested hash

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

Getting in to REQL has been really difficult.  It seemed intuitive at first from a straight up equals match standpoint, but gets really hard all of a sudden when I need to match data to a regular expression, and in a list.  Then I also want to pull just a single key/value pair out of the result set, within the scope of the thing that was matched.

That's a lot of words, so here's a close example of a single record:

```
{'Components':
    {'Drives': [
        {'Model': 'SeAGaTe', 'Serial': '04894', 'Size': '1000g'},
        {'Model': 'SeagATE', 'Serial': '11279', 'Size': '1000g'},
        {'Model': 'Intel', 'Serial': 'WX1748959TTR', 'Size': '250g'}
    ]},
    {'Motherboard':
        {'Model': 'X9DRT-HF+', 'Serial': 'VM128848'}
    }
},
{'Identity Information':
    {'Manufacturer': 'Supermicro', 'Serial': 'TT1434', 'Date Made': '2016-05-03'}
},
{'Logs':
    {'Main Log': '<LOG CONTENTS 5,000 LINES>', 'Messages Log': '<LOG CONTENTS 2,000 LINES>'}
}
```

I'm trying to search all records (about 8,000 entries) for:

- Drives that case-insensitive match model 'Seagate'

And then:

- Print the value of the 'Serial' key

I'm using the web interface of RethinkDB, and so far the closest I've come is:

```
r.db('production').table('logs').filter(
  r.row('Components')('Drives').contains(  
    function(doc){
        return doc('Model').match("(?i)seagate").pluck('Serial')})
  )
```

The problem is that while this does filter results correctly, it does not appear to be showing me just the 'Serial' key.

If someone could give me an example of how to accomplish this, and explain why the answer works, I would be really grateful.

Comment: Hey @Locane, did one of us solve this for you?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you @Locane.

```
r.db('production').table('logs')('Components').map(r.row('Drives').filter(
  (doc) => {
    return doc('Model').match("(?i)seagate")
  }).pluck('Serial')
).concatMap(r.row)
```

The key here is `.concatMap` which bubbles up the individual objects in an array up the final result sequence.

We can see first that we do a `.map` on every `('Components')` field of the table. Then do a filter on that array matching for the `seagate` regex on the `'Model'` field. And for the drives that match, we pluck just the 'Serial' field from the result. Lastly, the `concatMap` takes the individual `[{ Serial : 'serial' }, {...}]` objects out of the array and puts them in the final result sequence.

Operating on an embedded array, not to mention an embedded array of objects, is always a little tricky.

Answer (score 0):

While this may slow, it will work:

```
r.db('production')('Components')('Drives')
  .concatMap(r.row)
  .filter(function(doc) {
    return doc('Model').match("(?i)seagate")
  })
  .pluck('Serial')
```

Basically, we try to grabd the `drives` field, and flatten them with `concatMap` since they are in an array. Then we filter use your condition, and finally `pluck` the field we want.